# Assigning unique ID's with PHP that stay the same each visit

Tags: php, content-management-system

Alright, so I'm using a service called Pagelime, which is an online CMS tool.  For my CMS to work, I need a unique ID for any element I wish to edit.

I am making a menu.  In order to increase ease of editing later on, I've made each menu item a php include, so I can edit the master file instead of a ton of other files.

HTML/PHP Example:

```
<!-- LENTIL SOUP -->    
<?php
$title = "Lentil Soup";
$description = "Swiss Chard / Lentils / Potatoes";
$price = "4";
include 'menuitem.php';
?>

<!-- Mujadara -->    
<?php
$title = "Mujadara";
$description = "Lentils / Rice / Carmelized Onion";
$price = "4";
include 'menuitem.php';
?>
```

Master "menuitem.php" PHP file:

```
<h2>
<span class="cms-editable" id="???"><?php echo $title;?></span> / <?php echo $price;?>
</h2>

<h3>
<?php echo $description;?>
</h3>
```

As you can see, I'm echoing the element title, and attempting to make it editable.  In order for it to work with pagelime, I need a unique and **constant** ID.

I tried using `<?php echo uniqid();?>`, but this will not work as it creates a new unique ID every time that the page is reloaded.  I need a solution that generates unique ID's consistently and assign the same unique ID to the correct element every time.

I think this can be done by specifying an order, e.g. the first menu item is "menu1", the second is "menu2" and so on.  I would like to avoid something like this as it will make editing the menu a pain later on.  Is this impossible to do, then?  I can't see how the computer would be able to differentiate items without order.

If there is a solution using javascript, please feel free to answer with that code too.

Comment: No, just PHP includes.

Comment: i would suggest switching to a db as soon as possible.

Comment: Could you explain the benefits?  I'm not managing a website, I'm just trying to make basic things easily edited by my client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the menu item titles are unique, I would use those:

```
$id = str_replace(" ","_",strtolower($title)); // lentil_soup
```

Comment: Oh, wow!  Can't believe I didn't think of that.  I'll see if it works, but I'm unsure since I have both a dinner and lunch menu with items of the same value.  Maybe it will work because I hide the other when viewing another...  it'll work well for the title and description but perhaps not for the price, if the HTML is valid. brb...

Comment: @AlexanderLozada Do you have some other variable (category or something) that indicates lunch or dinner? If so, just combine them.

Comment: For the dinner menu, I think I'll add a variable like dinner=true, and then if that value is true in my master php, I'll append something like "dinner" to the ID.  Thanks!